# Why this statement comes to output?

Tags: c++

I have a question about this code:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A(){cout<<"A no parameter ";}
    A(string s){cout<<"A string parameter";}
    A(A &a){cout<<"A object A parameter";}
    
};

class B:public A
{
public:
    B(){cout<<"B no parameters";}
    B(string s){cout<< "B strig parameter";}
    B(int s){cout<<"B int parameter";}
    
};


int main() {
 

    A a2("Test");
    B b1(10);
    B b2(b1);

    
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I get this result:

```
A string parameterA no parameter B int parameterA object A parameterProgram ended with exit code: 0"
```

I am actually not sure why the statement `A no parameter` shows up, even though I did not assign the statement about it.

I am studying coding for now, so I am glad if you explain this.

Comment: During construction of an object of a derived class, its base class subobject has to be constructed first, hence the call to `A`'s constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that in

```
B(string s) /*...*/ {cout<< "B strig parameter";}
//and
B(int s) /*...*/  {cout<<"B int parameter";}
```

that in the `/*...*/`  part you have an empty [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).  That means the compiler will insert one for you for the base class. Because of that the constructors actually become

```
B(string s) : A() {cout<< "B strig parameter";}
//and
B(int s) : A() {cout<<"B int parameter";}
```

and the `A()` part is what is calling `A`'s default constructor.

Comment: I see that.
So the A() part always comes with every constructor in B class even though I did not write :A() in every part, did it?

Comment: @Sho Yes.  All class members, and that includes base classes, must be initialized in the member initialization list.  If you don't, the compiler will insert a default initializer for you.